# Whats the genre of Hamilton Songs (Washington on your Side)

Tags: genre

What is the genre of Washington on your side,

, as performed in Hamilton?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The songs from Hamilton are almost their own subgenre. I'd call this "Broadway Hip-Hop" or "Hip-Hop Show Tunes." It has a strong underground hip-hop influence, but it's also closely related to modern show tunes such as the *Rent* score.